Extracting Coq Lists to Lazy OCaml Lists?
When I use the following,
Require Import Coq.extraction.Extraction.
Require Import Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlNatInt.
Require Import Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlBasic.

Extraction Language OCaml.

Coq extracts lists as OCaml lists:
Extract Inductive list => "list" [ "[]" "(::)" ].

How can I extract these lists to a lazy variant of lists in OCaml?
I have tried the following:
Extract Inductive list => "Seq.t" [ "Seq.Nil" "Seq.Cons" ].

but this does not work since the OCaml Seq has a slightly different type for the Cons constructor. The type for the Cons constructor in Seq seems to be
| Cons : a -> (() -> Seq a) -> Seq a

What is the simplest way for me to use lazy lists in the extracted version?

Are you talking about Seq as described here? If so, I would extract list to Seq.t, nil to fun _ -> Seq.Nil and cons to fun a l _ -> Seq.Cons a l, which have the right types.

@MevenLennon-Bertrand could you explain? Extract Inductive list => "Seq.t" [ "fun _ -> Seq.Nil" "fun a l _ -> Seq.Cons a l" ]. does not work, especially for pattern matching

The solution seems to be the following
Extract Inductive list => "Seq.t" [ "(fun _ -> Seq.Nil)" "(fun pat _ -> let (x, xs) = pat in Seq.Cons(x, xs))" ]
    "(fun fNil fCons l -> match l () with Seq.Nil -> fNil () | Seq.Cons (x, xs) -> fCons x xs)".

This produces extracted code like the following:
let rec map f l =
  (fun fNil fCons l -> match l () with Seq.Nil -> fNil () | Seq.Cons (x, xs) -> fCons x xs)
    (fun _ -> (fun _ -> Seq.Nil))
    (fun a t -> (fun pat _ -> let (x, xs) = pat in Seq.Cons(x, xs)) ((f a), (map f t)))
    l

